# Need help on calculating operational complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, pascal, time-complexity

The algorithm is taken from great "Algorithms and Programming: Problems and Solutions" by Alexander Shen (namely exercise 1.1.28).

*Following is my translation from Russian so excuse me for mistakes or ambiguity. Please correct me if you feel so.*

### What should algorithm do

> With given natural *n* algorithm calculates the number of solutions of
>   inequality
>
> ```
> x*x + y*y < n
> ```
>
> in natural (non-negative) numbers without using
>   manipulations on real numbers

### In Pascal

```
k := 0; s := 0;

{at this moment of execution
 (s) = number of solutions of inequality with
 x*x + y*y < n, x < k}
while k*k < n do begin
  l := 0; t := 0;

  while k*k + l*l < n do begin
    l := l + 1;
    t := t + 1;
  end;

  {at this line 
   (t) = number of solutions of k*k + y*y < n
   for given (k) with y>=0}
  k := k + 1;
  s := s + t;
end;

{k*k >= n, so s = number of solutions of inequality}
```

---

Further in the text Shen says briefly that number of operations performed by this algorithm is "proportional to *n*, as one can calculate". So I ask you *how* one can calculate that with strict mathematics.

Comment: Noticed that placing "<n" inside the paragraph keeps the remaining part from displaying. Be aware!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two loops, one inside the other.

The external has this condition: `k*k < n` so `k` goes from `0` up to `SQRT(n)`

and the internal loop has this condition: `k*k + l*l < n` so `l` goes from `0` up to `SQRT(n-k^2)`. But this is snaller than `SQRT(n)`

So, the maximum iterations is less than `SQRT(n) * SQRT(n)` which is `n` and in every iteration a constant number of operations is done.

Comment: That's what I wanted! 
Silly me! Figured out all but last of your statements myself.

Answer (score 2):

The number of operation done by nested loops is a multiplication of the 2 lenghts

for example:

```
for i=1 to 5
 for j = 1 to 10
  print j+i
 end
end
```

will print 5*10 = 50 times

In your example the outer loop runs sqrt(n) times -that is until k^2=n or k=sqrt(n).
the inner loop runs sqrt(n) times as well .
k is constant within the loop, and it will stop when k^2+l^2>n , the most times it could run would be at k=0 -> l^2>n => l>sqrt(n) .
So the total number of iterations is at most sqrt(n)*sqrt(n) - O(n)

Answer (score 1):

The time taken by your algorithm is proportional to the number of operations made. Therefore, you just have to calculate that the time taken by your algorithm is proportional with an increasing size of the input (n). You can do so by timing the algorithm's completion with a wide range of n's and plotting the `n vs time` graph. Doing so should give you a linear graph.

Comment: Thank you for response. Already done that, and run-time is really consistent with proposal. What I want is rather strict mathematical approach without running it on machine.